# Automating Google chrome extenions with sahi

Tags: google-chrome-extension, automation, sahi, webautomation, navigatetourl

We are automating chrome extension with sahi.

we have loaded our chrome profile with sahi with extension added on profile.

we weren't able to get dom elements of extensions.

so we are navigating to the url: chrome-extension:/extension_id/popup.html

but sahi doesn't navigate to this url.

but i have read with selenium we are able to get it.

Please help me out, with this automation

Comment: So when you open the browser, is chrome extension added to your chrome?

Comment: @peter : yes extension is showing on my chrome browser, but i am not able to get its dom elements.

Comment: Did you tried manually  navigating to the url: chrome-extension:/extension_id/popup.html  ?

Comment: Yes. We tried manually the extension is displaying on the webpage. we are able to inspecting elements of extension. but with sahi wehn we are navigating.

Comment: _navigateTo("chrome-extension://Extension_id/html/popup.html");

Comment: Also we have tried with : _navigateTo("chrome-extension://Extension_id/popup.html");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I understand the problem here. But if you want to change some options on chrome. I use this [Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to find correct option to set when set browser on 'browser_types.xml`.

For example:

```
<options>--no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$userDir\browser\chrome\profiles\sahi$threadNo --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:$port --disable-popup-blocking --always-authorize-plugins --allow-outdated-plugins --enable-npapi --incognito</options>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject Sahi script into the pages of extension. One way to achieve this is as below.

1. Download the extension source code.
2. Then modifying the html pages such that Sahi injects its script in these pages.
3. Post this, you can pack the extension again. Load this modified extension into the browser.
4. Now you should be able to automate the pages of extension.

Reference: [Sahi Pro Documentation](https://resources.sahipro.com/docs/using-sahi/automate-browser-extensions.html)